# Nuxt/Vue-Router Navigation Guards Reroute to Dynamic Route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I currently develop an SPA web application using nuxt 2.7.1 as part of my bachelor's thesis.

On some of my pages I have set up `beforeRouteEnter` navigation guards to check whether a user may access the page. If not, I want to redirect the user to a dynamic route (namely `/info/1`).

When accessing the page protected by the navigation guard, Nuxt displays an error page stating `This page could not be found`, although the URL is correct and a simple reload at the error page correctly leads me to the dynamic route.

I am currently using the navigation guard in the following way:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  if (!isValidAccess()) {
    console.warn("illegal access");
    next(`/info/1`);
  } else next();
}
```

For clarification, my directory structure looks as follows:

```
pages
  |__ info
  |    |__ _index.vue (redirect target)
  |__ shop
       |__ _index.vue (with navigation guard)
```

I have tried experimenting with the argument passed to `next()` but so far without success. When implementing another `beforeRouteEnter` in the target route and logging the `to` parameter, everything seems normal.

I hope you guys can help me. I already spent too much time on this issue.

Best regards

**EDIT:**

I have created a minimal example, where the routing to a dynamic route works without problems... https://codesandbox.io/embed/codesandboxnuxt-t1d0e

I will update the question when I find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - on landing page (index) you get redirected to your `/info/1` dynamic route. Is this what you want?

https://codesandbox.io/embed/codesandboxnuxt-vvbrt

The only thing I've done was wrapping your dynamic route in `<no-ssr>` tag to get rid of an error. Your component is not compatible with SSR.